# Adding multi addEventListener to specific function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom-events, addeventlistener

I want to do multi `AddEventListener` to specific function, but the result is not what I want.
I get always the last child on the list.

Why?

This is the code:

First section:

```
<script>  
    var inside_elm= new Array();
    inside_elm[1]="inside_e1";
    inside_elm[2]="inside_e2";
    inside_elm[3]="inside_e3";
    
    var kk = {      
        showBox :function(elm){
            alert(elm);
            document.getElementById(elm).style.display='block';
        }
    }
    
    function load() {
        var e_elm= new Array();
        e_elm[1]="e1";
        e_elm[2]="e2";
        e_elm[3]="e3";
    
        for(var i=1;i<3;i++){
            var k=e_elm[i];
            alert(inside_elm[i]);
    
            document.getElementById(e_elm[i]).addEventListener('click',function(){kk.showBox(inside_elm[i])},false);
        }
    }
    </script>
```

The body:

```
  <body onload="load();">
    <div id="e1">
        e1
        <div id="inside_e1" style="display:none;">inside_e1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="e2">
        e2
        <div id="inside_e2" style="display:none;">inside_e2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="e3">
        e3
        <div id="inside_e3" style="display:none;">inside_e3</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing div tag for `<div id="e2">`. EDIT: Someone fixed it (maybe you), but make sure that doesn't have an effect on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically down to the fact that it doesn't evaluate 'i' until the function executes, by which stage it's set to 3.

What you want to do is use something like the following:

```
for(var i=1;i<4;i++){
    var k=e_elm[i];
    alert(inside_elm[i]);

    var elm = document.getElementById(e_elm[i]);
    elm.inside_elm = inside_elm[i];
    elm.addEventListener('click', function(){kk.showBox(this.inside_elm)},false);
}
```

Comment: thanks man, this fix work great, but when i added more one element and i increased the counter in one , the last div is opened with more one div why ?? how the logic of this for is work ?

Comment: i fount the problem !!! i was missing closed tag on the div, your script work great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it is down to the following, or at least it won't help matters.

```
for(i = 1;i < 3;i++){
....
}
```

Will only access the first two atoms of your array and will exit the loop before iterating the third time. Try

```
for(i = 1;i < 4;i++){
....
}
```

Similarly it is good practice to start array indices at 0 in which case

```
for(i = 0;i<3;i++){
....
}
```

would iterate through each (assuming the start index is 0)

Comment: As an extension it might be worth using.  <array variable>.length instead of a static value.

Comment: this is not an answer, someone can help me with my problem ?

Comment: i check your idea and it work, but this is not complete answer the best answer is above